# Slope and its relationship with angles

Tags: numpy, angle

I have been using numpy's `polyfit` function to get a linear fit to some data. And I have gotten some *slopes*. However the idea of slopes have gotten my head very confused.

I am getting slopes of 0.0142 and of 391! quite different.

What does a slope of 391 actually means? Take a look at this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xr=np.arange(100)
yr=0.0142*xr
yr2=391*xr

plt.plot(xr,yr,yr2)

print("The angle is:",np.degrees(np.arctan(391)))
```

[image]

`The angle is: 89.8534637990051`

There is no way that that angle is 89.8 degrees!

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

slope = `391` means for every unit change in your `x`, `y` changes by `391`. The angle is fact `89.8` and you cannot see it in your plot because your `x` and `y` axis have different scales. If you set them to a same scale (i.e. same unit length) you will see an angle of `89.8`.

Comment: So slope is not a good term to check for the trend of a timed data?

Comment: @KansaiRobot I think it depends on what you are trying to achieve. It is objective dependent. Slope is only one of the metrics you can look at.

Comment: Thanks. I will post a question about this.